# How do I connect/disconnect/configure a wireless network in python?

Tags: python, windows, wifi, windows-xp

I'm looking to see if there is a way to connect or disconnect to a wireless network in python, preferably a way that would work for both public and secured networks if I supplied the password. If I can configure the options about wireless, that would be an added bonus (ex. see all networks in range, see information about networks in range (like encryption type)). I run a windows computer, so I see many answers to this question in Linux, or other operating systems, but none in windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably have to use one of the DLLs in windows for that. Using [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) you can get access to the win32 API from Python.

It looks like the [functions from wlanapi.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa816369%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), starting with [WlanOpenHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WlanEnumInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might do what you want.

**Edit:** For example code, see the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851233/how-can-i-retrieve-the-signal-strength-of-nearby-wireless-lan-networks-on-window?rq=1).

Comment: Well, could you explain how I could do that? I didn't see anything on making enums in ctypes and it required definition of an enum type "WLAN_CONNECTION_MODE".

Comment: An `enum` in C is basically just a shortcut for making a list of integer constants, starting with 0 and incrementing with 1, unless specified otherwise. So if you look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, `wlan_connection_mode_profile` is 0, `wlan_connection_mode_temporary_profile` is 1, up to `wlan_connection_mode_invalid` is 5.