# List All Wireless Networks Python for PC

Tags: python, wifi, wireless

I am trying to find out how I can list all of the available wireless networks in Python. I am using Windows 8.1.

Is there a built-in function I can call, or through a library?

Please kindly show me the code which prints the list.

Comment: Check the scan() function in this file: https://github.com/changyuheng/pywinwifi/blob/master/src/winwifi/main.py

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll want the `subprocess` module and a windows command:

```
import subprocess
results = subprocess.check_output(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "network"])
```

A little extra to just get SSID's.

```
results = results.decode("ascii") # needed in python 3
results = results.replace("\r","")
ls = results.split("\n")
ls = ls[4:]
ssids = []
x = 0
while x < len(ls):
    if x % 5 == 0:
        ssids.append(ls[x])
    x += 1
print(ssids)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: ["netsh", "wlan", "show", "all"] gives more information, including the Access Point MAC Adresses (BSSIDD), if anyone needs those.

Comment: @LuWi i tryed with "all" but fails with: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5996: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @rodrigorf You might try decoding the text as Unicode: results = results.decode("utf8")

Comment: @weirdev i am getting this error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'netsh': 'netsh', i am using linux

Comment: @3bu1 This answer is specifically for windows, as that is what OP was asking about. For Linux, you can do a similar thing by calling subprocess.check_output() with the proper command for your distro to list networks. You will have to parse the output differently as it will not be formatted the same as the windows output.

Answer (score 9):

This is a question from the olden days, but even at the time the accepted answer could have been much more Pythonic - e.g.,

```
r = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "network"], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
ls = r.split("\n")
ssids = [k for k in ls if 'SSID' in k]
```

If you just want to SSID names in a list, change the `ssids =` line to

```
ssids = [v.strip() for k,v in (p.split(':') for p in ls if 'SSID' in p)]
```

Comment: Works perfectly. However, Windows sometimes needs to be kicked to show SSID that was recently activated. Any idea how to do that? I am doing that manually by clicking on network icon on the Windows task bar. :-(

Answer (score -4):

`c:\netsh`

`C:\netsh\wlan`

`c:\netsh\wlan)Show all`