# Wifi scanning and displaying using python ran by php

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi2

The goal is for the user to select a WiFi network. I'm running a webserver with php and would like to list the available networks.

The idea would be to have the user to press a scan button on the web page, which will then display a list of networks. User will then be allowed to choose which network they want to connect to. I am currently thinking of running a python script that gets the info.

Then the selected network will be saved in the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` for connection.

Comment: Check out the subprocess module. And this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31868561/5352244

Comment: Hi, I'll check it out. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I just tried it out. I encountered this error. FileNotFoundError [Errno2] No such file or directory :'netsh'
Any idea what it could mean?

Comment: Thats for windows, you will need to use subprocess with the raspberry pi terminal commands that display the info you want , I dont have a clue about raspberry pi.

Comment: I see, thanks anyways.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the question to have shorter sentences and clearer overview of what you're trying to accomplish. As a side note, you may want to explain why you want to use python to obtain the information, when you're already running php. Good luck!

Comment: I used python as I didn't know that Php was capable of scanning of wifi. @Melvyn

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to run python, since the information is easiest obtained by running `wpa_cli`. Php uses [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec) to run commands, which is the equivalent of `os.system` and to some extent `subprocess.check_output` in python.

You have to run two commands in order. If the first fails, the second has no use as the WiFi card is not able to scan.

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 scan
```

This should return "OK" and `wlan0` is the name of the wireless interface as shown by `ifconfig`. This is typically wlan0 and does not change over time, only when more WiFi cards are added to the pi.

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 scan_results
```

This returns several lines with a header:

```
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
b2:c2:87:77:62:73       2437    -50     [WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]    Ziggo
1c:3a:de:c3:f8:cf       2472    -54     [WPA2-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPS][ESS]  HZN246837438
```

You can discard the first line and split the rest of the lines at whitespace. Php can do this and make sure you allow at maximum 4 splits (resulting in 5 elements).

I'm doing exactly what you want, on a rpi-3, with Django (python). For a webserver with php the process is the same.

Comment: Hi Melvyn, thanks for the information. I tried the commands you said in the terminal of thr RPi and it worked. Also, when you said that Php can do that, does it mean I just have to type the exact same commands into a php file and run it?

Comment: I linked shell_exec, forgot to do that initially. So type the commands as argument to the `shell_exec` function.