# Is there a python module that enables wifi connections and works with windows?

Tags: python, wifi

I cant seem to find an easy to use wifi module that enables connection establishing that works with windows.

Comment: any news about this question?

Comment: Hey, I've looked over that previous question, and I still don't know how or what function I use to connect to a wireless access point. (Sorry, I'm still a bit of a noob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manage wirless network in Python, you should refer to the DDL for Wlan API and use **ctypes** to open it in Python.

You can find an example of such code in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851233/how-can-i-retrieve-the-signal-strength-of-nearby-wireless-lan-networks-on-window?rq=1).