# Java Application to read WiFi Signal and SSID?

Tags: java, wifi, signals, ssid

I've been searching a lot about this topic but I didn't find anything useful up till now, I want to create a simple application that can read

1. WiFi Signal Strength
2. SSID of AP

using Java. Is this possible, if yes then how?

Also i have another question, can I make the same application using J2ME?

Comment: You're dealing with hardware on a pretty low level, which generally requires dealing with the OS of your system. What OS are you running?

Comment: Well i'm running on Windows , What should i import to my program to be able to read this information from my Wireless adapter ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799223/java-application-to-read-wifi-signal-and-ssid

Comment: You'll likely need native code, for starters maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192376/wlan-api-for-getting-signal-strenth

Comment: @NickODell: Are you aware you linked to THIS QUESTION?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you would have to get an adapter from Riverbed, AirPcap.  They have an API you can consume with native code.  Once you compile a DLL you can use JNI to talk to that.