# Refresh WiFi network list with 'WlanScan' (convert api syntax from c# to vba... or a workaround?)

Tags: c#, vba, winapi, wifi, bssid

**I need to refresh Window's list of wireless networks.**

I'll gladly accept any workaround that I can automate (cmdline, wmi, etc) directly *or indirectly* from VBA. (I'm using Windows 7 Home 64-bit with Office 365 Pro 64-bit.)

I can list the networks programmatically a couple ways including `netsh`, or the code below, but **the list does not refresh** unless I physically click the [image: net] Network Connection icon on the taskbar's Notification area.

- The list does *not* auto-update every 60 seconds as some docs state.
- **Disconnect+Reconnecting the NIC is *not* a feasible/sustainable option.**

I think I'm **not getting the handle** from [WlanOpenHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/27bfa0c1-4443-47a4-a374-326f553fa3bb) as required and I'm green at converting C to VBA.

No errors but WlanScan returns unknown code `1168`.

- I adapted from the VB version here: **[wlanscan (wlanapi)](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wlanapi.wlanscan#)**
- MSDN documentation: **[WlanScan function](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanscan)**

---

> ### Related bits:

Here's the **function declaration for `VB`,** adapted:

```vb
Public Shared Function WlanScan(ByVal hClientHandle As IntPtr, _
   ByRef pInterfaceGuid As Guid, ByVal pDot11Ssid As IntPtr, _
   ByVal pIeData As IntPtr, ByVal pReserved As IntPtr) As UInteger
End Function
```

...and an example of **function usage in `C#`**:

```
Guid g;
//wlanHndl is the handle returned previously by calling [WlanOpenHandle]
for (int i = 0; i < infoList.dwNumberOfItems; i++)
{
g = infoList.InterfaceInfo[i].InterfaceGuid;
uint resultCode=WlanScan(wlanHndl, ref g, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
if (resultCode != 0)
    return;
}
```

...and **how to open the handle, in `C++`** (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3193613/8112776)):

```
dwResult = WlanOpenHandle(dwMaxClient, NULL, &dwCurVersion, &hClient);
if (dwResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    wprintf(L"WlanOpenHandle failed with error: %u\n", dwResult);
    return 1;
    // You can use FormatMessage here to find out why the function failed
}
```

---

> <sub>"Un-hidden:"</sub>
>
> ### Obtain (cached) list of wireless networks:

The code to list the networks **works great** - except for not refreshing on it's own. (Previously I was parsing the text output of `netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid`, which had the same issue.)

I had previously removed this section because its lengthy and seems to work fine except for the refresh. -)

```
Option Explicit  'section's source: vbforums.com/showthread.php?632731
Private Const DOT11_SSID_MAX_LENGTH As Long = 32
Private Const WLAN_MAX_PHY_TYPE_NUMBER As Long = 8
Private Const WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_CONNECTED As Long = 1
Private Const WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_HAS_PROFILE As Long = 2

Private Type GUID  'from cpearson.com
    Data1 As Long: Data2 As Integer:  Data3 As Integer:  Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Private Type WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO
    ifGuid As GUID: InterfaceDescription(255) As Byte: IsState As Long
End Type

Private Type DOT11_SSID
    uSSIDLength As Long:            ucSSID(DOT11_SSID_MAX_LENGTH - 1) As Byte
End Type

Private Type WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK
    strProfileName(511) As Byte:    dot11Ssid As DOT11_SSID
    dot11BssType As Long:           uNumberOfBssids As Long
    bNetworkConnectable As Long:    wlanNotConnectableReason As Long
    uNumberOfPhyTypes As Long:      dot11PhyTypes(WLAN_MAX_PHY_TYPE_NUMBER - 1) As Long
    bMorePhyTypes As Long:          wlanSignalQuality As Long
    bSEcurityEnabled As Long:       dot11DefaultAuthAlgorithm As Long
    dot11DefaultCipherAlgorithm As Long: dwflags As Long: dwReserved As Long
End Type

Private Type WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST
    dwNumberOfItems As Long: dwIndex As Long: InterfaceInfo As WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO
End Type

Private Type WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST
    dwNumberOfItems As Long:  dwIndex As Long: Network As WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK
End Type

Declare PtrSafe Function WlanOpenHandle Lib "Wlanapi.dll" (ByVal dwClientVersion As Long, _
                ByVal pdwReserved As Long, ByRef pdwNegotiaitedVersion As Long, _
                ByRef phClientHandle As Long) As Long

Declare PtrSafe Function WlanEnumInterfaces Lib "Wlanapi.dll" (ByVal hClientHandle As Long, _
                ByVal pReserved As Long, ppInterfaceList As Long) As Long

Declare PtrSafe Function WlanGetAvailableNetworkList Lib "Wlanapi.dll" ( _
                ByVal hClientHandle As Long, pInterfaceGuid As GUID, ByVal dwflags As Long, _
                ByVal pReserved As Long, ppAvailableNetworkList As Long) As Long

Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, _
                Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Declare PtrSafe Sub WlanFreeMemory Lib "Wlanapi.dll" (ByVal pMemory As Long)

Type WiFis
  ssid As String: signal As Single
End Type

Public Function GetWiFi() As WiFis()
'returns an array of custom type WiFis (1st interface only)

    Dim udtList As WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST, udtAvailList As WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST, udtNetwork As WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK
    Dim lngReturn As Long, lngHandle As Long, lngVersion As Long, lngList As Long, lngAvailable As Long
    Dim lngStart As Long, intCount As Integer, ssid As String, signal As Single, wifiOut() As WiFis
    n = 0

    lngReturn = WlanOpenHandle(2&, 0&, lngVersion, lngHandle) 'get handle
    If lngReturn <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Couldn't get wlan handle (Code " & lngReturn & ")"
        Exit Function
    End If

    lngReturn = WlanEnumInterfaces(ByVal lngHandle, 0&, lngList) 'enumerate <*first interface only*>
    CopyMemory udtList, ByVal lngList, Len(udtList)
    lngReturn = WlanGetAvailableNetworkList(lngHandle, udtList.InterfaceInfo.ifGuid, 2&, 0&, lngAvailable) 'get network list
    CopyMemory udtAvailList, ByVal lngAvailable, LenB(udtAvailList)
    intCount = 0
    lngStart = lngAvailable + 8

    Do
        CopyMemory udtNetwork, ByVal lngStart, Len(udtNetwork) ' Populate avail. network structure
        ssid = Replace(StrConv(udtNetwork.dot11Ssid.ucSSID, vbUnicode), Chr(0), "")
        If Len(ssid) < 4 Then ssid = "(Unnamed)"
        signal = CSng(udtNetwork.wlanSignalQuality) / 100
        '[Signal] = 0 to 100 which represents the signal strength (100 Signal)=(-100dBm RSSI), (100 Signal)=(-50dBm RSSI)

        If udtNetwork.dwflags = 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve wifiOut(n)
            wifiOut(n).ssid = ssid
            wifiOut(n).signal = signal
        Else
            'skipping networks with [dwflags] > 0
            'I *think* that's what I'm supposed to do
            'Returns 3 for currently connected network, 2 for networks that have profiles
        End If

        intCount = intCount + 1
        lngStart = lngStart + Len(udtNetwork)
    Loop Until intCount = udtAvailList.dwNumberOfItems
    WlanFreeMemory lngAvailable     'clean up memory
    WlanFreeMemory lngList

    GetWiFi = wifiOut   'Success! (function is populated with cached network list)

End Function
```

---

> *<sub>...and the problem:</sub>*
>
> ## Refresh network list using `WlanScan`?

This does *not* generate a VBA error, but *does* return code `1168` (which I can't identify)/ ([Source](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wlanapi.wlanscan))

```vb
'Added blindly:'wlanui type library (wlanui.dll) and "wlan pref iua" (wlanconn.dll)

Public Type DOT11_SSID 
   uSSIDLength As LongPtr: ucSSID As String
End Type

Private Type GUID 'from cpearson.com/excel/CreateGUID.aspx
    Data1 As LongPtr: Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer: Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

#If Win64 Then 'also new to Office-64bit, but seems okay
    Declare PtrSafe Function WlanScan Lib "Wlanapi.dll" _
        (ByVal hClientHandle As LongPtr, ByRef pInterfaceGuid As GUID, _
        ByVal pDot11Ssid As LongPtr, ByVal pIeData As LongPtr, _
        ByVal pReserved As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare WlanScan Lib "Wlanapi.dll" _
        (ByVal hClientHandle As LongPtr, ByRef pInterfaceGuid As GUID, _
        ByVal pDot11Ssid As LongPtr, ByVal pIeData As LongPtr, _
        ByVal pReserved As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#End If

Sub test_RefreshNetworkList()
    Dim hresult As LongPtr, phClientHandle As Long, pdwNegotiatedVersion As Long
    Dim retVal As Longptr, g As GUID
    hresult = WlanOpenHandle(2&, 0&, pdwNegotiatedVersion, phClientHandle)
    retVal = WlanScan(phClientHandle, g, 0, 0, 0)
    Select Case retVal
        Case 87: Debug.Print "ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER"
        Case 6: Debug.Print "ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE"
        Case 8: Debug.Print "ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY"
        Case Else: Debug.Print "RPC_STATUS : " & retVal  ' "misc errors"
    End Select
End Sub
```

---

Surely there's a roundabout way to refresh the network list from VBA?  I'm cool with workarounds that I can automate... anything?!

[image: paw]  Thanks!

---

> ## Edit:

I changed `Long` to **`LongPtr`** in the applicable (I think) spots.  Same error.

Here's the `WlanOpenHandle` and `WlanScan` definitions.

```
Declare PtrSafe Function WlanOpenHandle Lib "Wlanapi.dll" 
    (ByVal dwClientVersion As LongPtr, _
     ByVal pdwReserved As LongPtr, 
     ByRef pdwNegotiaitedVersion As LongPtr, _
     ByRef phClientHandle As LongPtr           ) As LongPtr
```

(...it was also my first attempt time using compiler constants.)

```
#If Win64 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function WlanScan Lib "Wlanapi.dll" _
        (ByVal hClientHandle As LongPtr,
         ByRef pInterfaceGuid As GUID, _
         ByVal pDot11Ssid As LongPtr, 
         ByVal pIeData As LongPtr, _
         ByVal pReserved As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare WlanScan Lib "Wlanapi.dll" _
        (ByVal hClientHandle As LongPtr, 
         ByRef pInterfaceGuid As GUID, _
         ByVal pDot11Ssid As LongPtr, 
         ByVal pIeData As LongPtr, _
         ByVal pReserved As LongPtr     ) As LongPtr
#End If
```

Comment: IIR 1168 is "Element not found". Your Win64 function signatures are wrong - a .NET `IntPtr` should be a `LongPtr` in VBA. Can you edit the question to include your VBA `WlanOpenHandle` definition?

Comment: @Comintern -  Thanks - I made that change (still the same error).  I added the definitions for the two functions in question to the end of the question.

Comment: In the "hidden" revision, you are using `WlanEnumInterfaces` for `WlanGetAvailableNetworkList`, but not for `WlanScan`. You are supposed to use `WlanEnumInterfaces` there too, you cannot pass a pointer to empty GUID, that is what gets you 1168 `ERROR_NOT_FOUND` (as opposed to `ERROR_INVALID PARAMETER` that you would have gotten for passing a null pointer to guid).

Comment: @GSerg - All I got out of that is that I should "un-hide" that code if it's actually relevant to my problem.  So, this code block you speak of... what would it look like? :)

Comment: To clarify that I'm using Office 64 although not everyone will be, hence my (first) attempt at compiler tags on the api declarations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your main problem with not refreshing is that you're never closing your open handles. This can cause problems, as there shouldn't be multiple open handles afaik.

You use `WlanOpenHandle` to gain a handle to the interface, but after you're done with it and have the information you need, you should call `WlanCloseHandle` to close that handle and the associated connection.

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Function WlanCloseHandle Lib "Wlanapi.dll" ( _
  ByVal hClientHandle As LongPtr, _
  Optional ByVal pReserved As LongPtr) As Long
```

And at then end of your function:

```vb
    WlanCloseHandle lngHandle 'Close handle
    GetWiFi = wifiOut   'Success! (function is populated with cached network list)
End Function
```

Any error handler, if you're going to add one, should test if the handle isn't 0, and if it isn't, close it.

I've also changed various little things, such as using `LongPtr` for pointers to make your code 64-bit compatible (note: it's *not* VBA6 compatible, that requires a lot of conditional compilations), reworking your declarations to not use optional parameters, and some other little things.

I've tested the following code with 10 iterations on a device and got 10 different results:

Code:

```vb
Public Function GetWiFi() As wifis()
'returns an array of custom type WiFis (1st interface only)

    Dim udtList As WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST, udtAvailList As WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST, udtNetwork As WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK
    Dim lngReturn As Long, pHandle As LongPtr, lngVersion As Long, pList As LongPtr, pAvailable As LongPtr
    Dim pStart As LongPtr, intCount As Integer, ssid As String, signal As Single, wifiOut() As wifis
    Dim n As Long
    n = 0

    lngReturn = WlanOpenHandle(2&, 0&, lngVersion, pHandle) 'get handle
    If lngReturn <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Couldn't get wlan handle (Code " & lngReturn & ")"
        Exit Function
    End If

    lngReturn = WlanEnumInterfaces(ByVal pHandle, 0&, pList) 'enumerate <*first interface only*>
    CopyMemory udtList, ByVal pList, Len(udtList)
    lngReturn = WlanScan(pHandle, udtList.InterfaceInfo.ifGuid)
    lngReturn = WlanGetAvailableNetworkList(pHandle, udtList.InterfaceInfo.ifGuid, 2&, 0&, pAvailable) 'get network list
    CopyMemory udtAvailList, ByVal pAvailable, LenB(udtAvailList)
    intCount = 0
    pStart = pAvailable + 8

    Do
        CopyMemory udtNetwork, ByVal pStart, Len(udtNetwork) ' Populate avail. network structure
        ssid = Replace(StrConv(udtNetwork.dot11Ssid.ucSSID, vbUnicode), Chr(0), "")
        If Len(ssid) < 4 Then ssid = "(Unnamed)"
        signal = CSng(udtNetwork.wlanSignalQuality) / 100
        '[Signal] = 0 to 100 which represents the signal strength (100 Signal)=(-100dBm RSSI), (100 Signal)=(-50dBm RSSI)

        If udtNetwork.dwflags = 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve wifiOut(n)
            wifiOut(n).ssid = ssid
            wifiOut(n).signal = signal
        Else
            'skipping networks with [dwflags] > 0
            'I *think* that's what I'm supposed to do
            'Returns 3 for currently connected network, 2 for networks that have profiles
        End If

        intCount = intCount + 1
        pStart = pStart + Len(udtNetwork)
    Loop Until intCount = udtAvailList.dwNumberOfItems
    WlanFreeMemory pAvailable     'clean up memory
    WlanFreeMemory pList
    WlanCloseHandle pHandle 'Close handle
    GetWiFi = wifiOut   'Success! (function is populated with cached network list)
End Function
```

Types and constants:

```vb
Private Const DOT11_SSID_MAX_LENGTH As Long = 32
Private Const WLAN_MAX_PHY_TYPE_NUMBER As Long = 8
Private Const WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_CONNECTED As Long = 1
Private Const WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_HAS_PROFILE As Long = 2

Public Type GUID
    Data(15) As Byte
End Type

Private Type WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO
    ifGuid As GUID: InterfaceDescription(255) As Byte: IsState As Long
End Type

Private Type DOT11_SSID
    uSSIDLength As Long:            ucSSID(DOT11_SSID_MAX_LENGTH - 1) As Byte
End Type

Private Type WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK
    strProfileName(511) As Byte:    dot11Ssid As DOT11_SSID
    dot11BssType As Long:           uNumberOfBssids As Long
    bNetworkConnectable As Long:    wlanNotConnectableReason As Long
    uNumberOfPhyTypes As Long:      dot11PhyTypes(WLAN_MAX_PHY_TYPE_NUMBER - 1) As Long
    bMorePhyTypes As Long:          wlanSignalQuality As Long
    bSEcurityEnabled As Long:       dot11DefaultAuthAlgorithm As Long
    dot11DefaultCipherAlgorithm As Long: dwflags As Long: dwReserved As Long
End Type

Private Type WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST
    dwNumberOfItems As Long: dwIndex As Long: InterfaceInfo As WLAN_INTERFACE_INFO
End Type

Private Type WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST
    dwNumberOfItems As Long:  dwIndex As Long: Network As WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK
End Type

Public Type WiFis
  ssid As String: signal As Single
End Type
```

Function declarations:

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Function WlanOpenHandle Lib "Wlanapi.dll" (ByVal dwClientVersion As Long, _
                ByVal pdwReserved As LongPtr, ByRef pdwNegotiaitedVersion As Long, _
                ByRef phClientHandle As LongPtr) As Long

Declare PtrSafe Function WlanEnumInterfaces Lib "Wlanapi.dll" (ByVal hClientHandle As LongPtr, _
                ByVal pReserved As LongPtr, ByRef ppInterfaceList As LongPtr) As Long

Declare PtrSafe Function WlanGetAvailableNetworkList Lib "Wlanapi.dll" ( _
                ByVal hClientHandle As LongPtr, ByRef pInterfaceGuid As GUID, ByVal dwflags As Long, _
                ByVal pReserved As LongPtr, ByRef ppAvailableNetworkList As LongPtr) As Long


Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, _
                Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Declare PtrSafe Function WlanScan Lib "Wlanapi.dll" _
        (ByVal hClientHandle As LongPtr, ByRef pInterfaceGuid As GUID, _
        Optional ByVal pDot11Ssid As LongPtr, Optional ByVal pIeData As LongPtr, _
        Optional ByVal pReserved As LongPtr) As Long

Declare PtrSafe Function WlanCloseHandle Lib "Wlanapi.dll" ( _
  ByVal hClientHandle As LongPtr, _
  Optional ByVal pReserved As LongPtr) As Long


Declare PtrSafe Sub WlanFreeMemory Lib "Wlanapi.dll" (ByVal pMemory As LongPtr)
```

Test call to print the list:

```vb
Public Sub PrintWifis()
    Dim aWifis() As wifis
    aWifis = GetWiFi
    Dim l As Long
    For l = LBound(aWifis) To UBound(aWifis)
        Debug.Print aWifis(l).ssid; aWifis(l).signal
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: what would an example call to print the list out look like?

Comment: @QHarr Added test call (bottom of answer)

Comment: **Worked perfectly as-is**, thank you.  On 5 loops it's about 25x faster than my third [1st working] attempt (which parses the text output `netsh` and hackily open the Network Connections window to refresh data)

Answer (score 3):

Regarding these comments:

> the list does not refresh unless I physically click the Network Connection icon

and

> Surely there's a roundabout way to refresh the network list from VBA?
>   I'm cool with workarounds that I can automate... anything?!

Here's  a roundabout way: programmatically click the Network Connection Icon:

```
Sub ClickIt()
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "%windir%\explorer.exe ms-availablenetworks:"
End With
End Sub
```

You 'could' close it with a mouse_event after an application.wait when it takes some time to refresh

Comment: This is potentially just quick-and-dirty enough for my liking, although I'd be interested in closing the window too so the process is "somewhat" invisible to the user, but first off... I'm afraid **it doesn't work** at all... see error in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbS1G.png

Comment: WELL that got me down a deep rabbit-hole filled with wonder and more almost-solutions involving `explorer` from the command line. Example: `explorer ::{21ec2020-3aea-1069-a2dd-08002b30309d}\::{2227a280-3aea-1069-a2de-08002b30309d}` opens `ControlPanel\Printers`. Still no refreshed list but [Geoff Chappell''s site](//geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/explorer/cmdline.htm) and tons of interesting related stuff. Poking thru CLSIDs in regedit looks like `{7007ACCF-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}` or `{7007ACD1-3202-11D1-AAD2-00805FC1270E}` could be the fix but I give up again. Ideas? (Win7 btw)

Comment: In my Win10 it works perfectly, you could check this link: https://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/188220-windows-7-explorer-exe-file-does-not-have-program-associated-error.html#post1591625

Comment: You could try these 3 options, but I assume you'll run into same error: Shell "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe ms-availablenetworks:"
Shell "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\explorer.exe ms-availablenetworks:"
Shell "explorer.exe ms-availablenetworks:"

Comment: I'm not on Windows 10, but your answer seeded a day of research and experimentation (and learning - the best part of interactions like this on [so]!) - which *finally* resulted in me finding a working solution. Turns out, shortcuts like `ms-availablenetworks:` replaced CLSID's used by previous versions, starting with Windows 10 -  and with good reason...

Answer (score 2):

This project became a mission because it *seemed* straightforward, several times. My first attempt captured the output of `netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid` but I couldn't get the list to *refresh*. Thinking the refresh would be easy if I changed over to the API method (`WlanScan`+`WlanGetAvailableNetworkList`), I started from scratch before realizing I *still* couldn't refresh the data.

After posting this question, EvR's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52304593) eventually/finally led me to the ability to open/close the Network Connections list in the Windows notification area, which refreshed the cached text, so I re-wrote the process a third time, back to using `netsh`.  I finally got attempt #3 working (below), and then saw Erik's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52318440) which accomplishes the same result... but considerably less "hacky", and 25× faster.

So, I will obviously go with "final attempt #4", but figured I'd post this alternate answer anyhow, as some of the concepts are easily transferable to other problems where a quick <del>hack</del> *fix* is needed.

```
Option Compare Binary
Option Explicit

Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "Shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd _
    As LongPtr, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters _ 
    As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Public Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "User32.dll" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
    (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Public Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "User32.dll" () As LongPtr

Type WiFis
    ssid As String      'wifi network name
    signal As Single    'wifi signal strength%
End Type

Private Function IsNetworksWindow(hWnd As Long, nCaption As String) As Boolean
'returns TRUE if the window caption (title) of window [hWnd]=[nCaption]
    Dim title As String * 255
    GetWindowText hWnd, title, 255                                  'get window caption
    IsNetworksWindow = (nCaption = Left$(title, Len(nCaption)))
End Function

Sub RefreshWifiList()
'open "available networks" window (to refresh cached network list)
    Const clsID = "shell:::{38A98528-6CBF-4CA9-8DC0-B1E1D10F7B1B}" 'clsid of req'd window
    Const nCaption = "View Available Networks"                     'title of req'd  window
    Dim retVal As LongPtr
    retVal = ShellExecute(0, "open", clsID, "", "", 0)             'open clsID
    If retVal < 33 Then Stop    'Error. Full list here: [http://oehive.org/node/528]
    Do
    DoEvents: Loop While Not IsNetworksWindow(GetForegroundWindow, nCaption) 'wait for refresh
    ThisWorkbook.Activate: AppActivate Application.Caption           'return to Excel
End Sub

Public Function getCmdLineOutput(cmd As String) As String
'run cmdline in hidden window and return string of output
    Dim tmpFile As String: tmpFile = Environ("temp") & "\cmd_out.tmp" 'create tmp file
    If Dir(tmpFile) <> "" Then Kill tmpFile                         'delete tmp file
    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")                              'run cmdline command
        .Run "cmd /c """ & cmd & """ > " & tmpFile, 0, True         '0=Hide Window
    End With
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")                 'open fso
        getCmdLineOutput = Trim(.opentextfile(tmpFile).ReadAll())   'read temp file
        .DeleteFile tmpFile                                         'delete temp file
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetWiFi() As WiFis()
'extract [ssid]'s & [signal]'s from list to populate array of networks
    Dim stNet As String, pStart As Long, pStop As Long: pStop = 1
    Dim ssid As String, signal As String, wiFi() As WiFis: ReDim wiFi(0 To 0)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    RefreshWifiList                                                 'refresh wifi list
    stNet = getCmdLineOutput("netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid") 'get network list
    stNet = Mid$(stNet, InStr(stNet, "SSID"))                       'trim extraneous chars
    stNet = Replace(Replace(Replace(stNet, " ", ""), vbCrLf, ""), vbLf & vbLf, vbLf)

    Do While InStr(pStop, stNet, "SSID") > 0
        pStart = InStr(InStr(pStop, stNet, "SSID"), stNet, ":") + 1   'find ssid start
        pStop = InStr(pStart, stNet, "Networktype")                   'find ssid stop
        ssid = Mid$(stNet, pStart, pStop - pStart)                    'extract ssid
        pStart = InStr(pStop, stNet, "Signal:") + 7                   'find signal start
        pStop = InStr(pStart, stNet, "%")                             'find signal stop
        signal = CSng(Mid$(stNet, pStart, pStop - pStart)) / 100      'extract signal
        If signal = 0 Then Stop: If ssid = "" Then ssid = "(Unnamed)" 'validate

        ReDim Preserve wiFi(UBound(wiFi) + 1)                         'populate array
        wiFi(UBound(wiFi)).ssid = ssid: wiFi(UBound(wiFi)).signal = signal
    Loop

    GetWiFi = wiFi
End Function

Sub demo()
    Dim wiFi() As WiFis, netNum As Long
    wiFi() = GetWiFi()                                      'populate array of networks
    For netNum = 1 To UBound(wiFi)                          'loop through networks
        With wiFi(netNum)
            Debug.Print .ssid, Format(.signal, "0%")        'print ssid & signal
        End With
    Next netNum
End Sub

Sub timeTest_listNetworks()
    Dim wiFi() As WiFis, netNum As Long, n As Long
    Dim startTime As Single, allTime As Single: allTime = Timer
    For n = 1 To 5                      'repeat test 5x
        Erase wiFi()                    'clear array
        startTime = Timer
        wiFi() = GetWiFi()              'refresh array of networks
        For netNum = 1 To UBound(wiFi)  'loop through networks
            Debug.Print wiFi(netNum).ssid & "=" & Format(wiFi(netNum).signal, "0%") & " ";
        Next netNum
        Debug.Print "(" & Round(Timer - startTime, 1) & " sec)"
    Next n
    Debug.Print "Total: " & Round(Timer - allTime, 1) & " sec"
End Sub
```

---

### More Information:

- Geoff Chappell : [**`Explorer` Command Line**](https://geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/explorer/cmdline.htm)
- MS Docs : [**`ShellExecuteA` Function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea)
- OpenEdge : [**`ShellExecute` return codes**](http://www.oehive.org/node/528)
- MS Docs : [**`GetWindowTextA` Function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta)
- MS Docs : [**`GetForegroundWindow` Function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow)
- SS64 : [**`WScript.Shell.Run` Method**](https://ss64.com/vb/run.html)
- MS Docs : [**Scripting `FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile` Method**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method)
- MS Docs : [**`AppActivate` Statement**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/appactivate-statement)
- Stack Overflow : [**Convert Signal Strength% to RSSI dBm**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15798024)